# Maxlength not counting properly in chrome but does well in FF

Tags: html

I am using maxlength at a textarea, and using a JS to check the number of characters left. if i try to input a simple string

i.e:

> 1234567890

repeatedly the maxlength works perfectly but if i try to input a string like this:

> ```
> Welcome!
>
> 1. this is a test
> 2. this is a test
> 3. this is a test
>
> hahaahahahahahahaahahahahahahahhahaahahahahahahahahahahahaaaaaaaaaaaaaasddddddddddasdaasdasdasd
> ```

it stops on 6 characters left, but on FF it works perfectly.

I was trying to do some research on how maxlength works but it was to no success, so i was wondering why is maxlength not working perfectly on chrome. could it be because of the spaces and special characters inputted?

thank you

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The issue can be demonstrated using simple code like

```
<textarea maxlength=5 rows=2 cols=10></textarea>
```

On Firefox, you can then e.g. type “12”, press enter, and type “34”, and then you can’t type more. On Chrome, if you try to do the same, you cannot type any more after the “3”.

It seems that Chrome works correctly, Firefox doesn’t. The `maxlength` attribute for `textarea` is an HTML5 novelty, so the best definition for correctness is either the newest W3C HTML5 draft or the newest WHATWG HTML document, and they agree on this issue (and most other issues too).

By the [W3C HTML5 definition for `textarea`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/the-textarea-element.html#attr-textarea-maxlength), a line break in the value is canonicalized by the browser to CR LF (carriage return, linefeed, i.e. two control characters). So if you type “12”, press enterm, and type “3”, you have entered five characters, since the line break counts as two characters.

Spaces count as characters, and so do special characters. By the W3C HTML5 draft, some very special characters, namely characters outside Basic Multilingual Plane (BMP), are relly special: they count each as two characters, since the length is counted in 16-bit code units. But most people never used non-BMP characters.

Comment: Would you be kind enough to provide me with link of the characters and their count consumption. thank you. thanks for this info :)

Comment: The “count consumption” is specified in the HTML5 document cited. Any normal character consumes 1, any line break consumes 2, and any non-BMP character (character with Unicode number greater than FFFF hex.) consumes 2.

Comment: If you load the textarea value into JavaScript and get the `length`, it only counts newlines as a single character. Is that then a bug in Chrome's JavaScript?