# Javascript length and textarea maxlength don't match up

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, textarea

**Problem:** I have a javascript function that counts the number of characters in the textarea and outputs it to my console. I also have `maxlength` set on my textarea.
 The problem is, that sometimes my `sum` and textarea `maxlength` dont line up.

For example, the textarea would be blocking my input, but the sum varible would show me , that I still have characters left. Especially, when I type fast or when I insert multiple characters at the same time.

How can I solve this?
Thanks

---

**HTML:**

```
<textarea maxlength="100"></textarea>
```

**Javascript:**

```
var inputArea = $('textarea');
inputArea.keyup(function(){
   var sum = 100 - inputArea.val().length;
console.log(sum);
});
```

**JSFiddle**: http://jsfiddle.net/RnTHJ/3/

Comment: try `change` event...

Comment: I did, it won't even change the value then..

Comment: Check this out - http://jsfiddle.net/RnTHJ/9/ . Works fine

Comment: @Sann: I was able to break it..is there even a way of doing this? :D

Comment: Something must be wrong with your browser. It works awesome on mine.

Comment: @Sann: it seems like it works on some browsers and breaks on others..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are likely firing so many "keyup" events that when you type fast or enter multiple characters at a time the events are not necessarily finishing the the order they were fired, and you end up with a sum that is a couple characters old.

You might want to try a small timeout, and cancel the timeout each time you start a new one. Something like:

```
var timeoutVariable;
var inputArea = $('textarea');
inputArea.keyup(function(){
   window.clearTimeout(timeoutVariable);
   timeoutVariable = setTimeout(runSum(),100);
});

function runSum() {
   var sum = 100 - inputArea.val().length;
   console.log(sum);
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/RnTHJ/8/

Comment: thanks it looks like an interesting solution, but i can still "confuse" the sum variable..

Comment: Really? I haven't been able to break it so far. Try increasing the 100 millisecond time to a bit more.

Comment: Nope, it breaks. press enter and backspace a few times.. :)

Comment: Ah, the enter key. I'm seeing that some browsers count that as two characters, it's inconsistent. Line breaks are messing with your characters count.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11675997/maxlength-not-counting-properly-in-chrome-but-does-well-in-ff and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10030921/chrome-counts-characters-wrong-in-textarea-with-maxlength-attribute. Your javascript .length is going to have problems matching the maxlength check if there are line breaks.

Comment: You could go with pure js. Get rid of the maxlength attribute altogether. In javascript check the length, and if it exceeds 100 set it back with inputArea.val(inputArea.val().substr(0, 100));

Answer (score 1):

try keypress, it works : http://jsfiddle.net/RnTHJ/4/

Best would be [using the change event](http://jsfiddle.net/RnTHJ/7/) though.

EDIT:

How about using keydown & not re assigning from input length every time. ([fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/RnTHJ/10/))

```
var inputArea = $('textarea.test');

var sum = 100;

inputArea.keydown(function (evt) {
    var evt = window.event ? window.event : e;
    var k = evt.keyCode ? evt.keyCode : e.which;

    if(k>48) { 
        if(sum>0) sum--;
    }
    else {
         if(sum<100) sum++;   
    }

    $(this).siblings().text(sum);
});
```

As a sample, I check only for a random case 48... You could be checking for all the alphabets & numbers, if possible. The backspace checked explicitly with its keycode.

Comment: No, this has the same problem (for me). Try pressing the enter key lots of times... (Chrome on Win7)

Comment: keypress doesn't update on backspace. change doesn't update until you click/tab away from the textarea (onblur).

Comment: @jszobody yes, but keypress updates on the very first character press.

Comment: hm.. but at the end the sum still holds a number and textarea is blocking input. is there any other way?

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old thread but the only reason it won't match up in my experience is due to newline characters. If you hit enter/return in the field that actually counts as two characters (\r\n) against the maxlength validation not just one (\n) like most people would expect. Maybe that's the issue you're having with counts not matching up?